# Invoking AWS Lambda on desktop application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, automation, aws-lambda

I have a desktop application and it is a scientific instrument creating a file based output. 
Currently I have to upload the output file to my application using file picker.
I want to utilize AWS Lambda services on the file that very moment when it is generated.
My desktop is using Windows. The application is based on React.js.
I am flexible to switch to Linux based operating system and it is a corporate environment and hence there is good cloud storage.
Is it possible? If not any other workaround?

Comment: How big are the upload files?

Comment: The files are tiny. A megabyte at Max.

Comment: Ah ok. My answer should work for you. I hope it helps

Comment: The machine has its proprietary software which generates the output. I want the output to be automatically uploaded to S3.

Comment: Can you save the data to local storage? Then have a scheduled task move the files to s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lambda to have access to the file, it needs to be uploaded to AWS. Your app would upload it to one  S3 bucket, which would invoke a Lambda. The Lambda would process it, and write it to another s3 bucket. Your app would then download the processed file when it becomes available. The Lambda could also use SQS as a means of notifying the app after the file is processed.

For more information on using S3 events to invoke Lambda see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: Yes, I can use S3 but the file is produced and stored in local memory. I want the files to be uploaded to S3 when they are produced automatically without human intervention

Comment: Sure. Can you use the AWS SDK in your app and upload the file that way?

Comment: The machine has its proprietary software which generates the output. I want the output to be automatically uploaded to S3.

Comment: Generated by proprietary software.

Comment: So you mean that I can use the S3 folder sync tool to upload the files to Lambda. Once done, the file would be available for processing for my app?

Comment: Yes exactly that would be my approach